# Hibernate @Formula results in org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, calculated-columns

I've got following entity with calculated field `isIdle`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Customer.TABLE)
public class Customer {

    // ...

    @JsonIgnore
    private static final String IS_IDLE_SQL =
        "CASE WHEN (trunc(extract(epoch from now())) - coalesce(last_user_login_time,0) " +
        "> 5 * 24 * 3600 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END";

    @Formula(IS_IDLE_SQL)
    private Integer isIdle;

    public Integer getIsIdle() {
        return isIdle;
    }

    public void setIsIdle(Integer isIdle) {
        this.isIdle = isIdle;
    }
}
```

The field should be 0, if `last_user_login_time` contains UNIX timestamp which is in the last 5 days, and 1 otherwise.

As it is calculated, I have not corresponding column in my DB table.
When I deploy my application, I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: isIdle in public.customer
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:366)
```

Why does Hibernate try to find a column for this calculated field? 
The database uses PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by putting SQL statement right inside `@Formula` annotation, like this:

```
@Formula("CASE WHEN (trunc(extract(epoch from now())) - coalesce(last_user_login_time,0) " +
    "> 5 * 24 * 3600 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")
private Integer isIdle;
```